# Returning lowest value of a field from rows formed from joined tables

Tags: mysql, join

I'm just getting a hang of joins and whatnot in mysql. I've got a little query I'm working on which I'd like to return the lowest prices for a product and a respective client/company based on which promotions they belong to. I'm able to get the product, company, and price, but I can't get the lowest price.

The current output looks like this:

```
select G.promotionid, name, startdate, enddate, issuer, company_name, productid, 
promotionprice from promotion_general G inner join company_promotions C on G.promotionid =
C.promotionid inner join productpromotions P on G.promotionid = P.promotionid order by
company_name, productid;
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+----------------+
| promotionid | name       | startdate  | enddate    | issuer         | company_name           | productid | promotionprice |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+----------------+
|           3 | promo2     | 2014-05-08 | 2014-06-08 | zakiir         | Company C              | DEMOB     |         300.00 |
|           1 | test promo | 2014-07-08 | 2014-08-08 | root@localhost | Company F              | DEMOA     |         500.00 |
|           3 | promo2     | 2014-05-08 | 2014-06-08 | zakiir         | Company F              | DEMOB     |         300.00 |
|           2 | promo2     | 2014-08-08 | 2014-09-08 | zakiir         | Company F              | DEMOB     |         650.00 |
|           1 | test promo | 2014-07-08 | 2014-08-08 | root@localhost | Company F              | DEMOB     |         600.00 |
|           1 | test promo | 2014-07-08 | 2014-08-08 | root@localhost | Company F              | DEMOC     |         650.00 |
|           1 | test promo | 2014-07-08 | 2014-08-08 | root@localhost | Company G              | DEMOA     |         500.00 |
|           1 | test promo | 2014-07-08 | 2014-08-08 | root@localhost | Company G              | DEMOB     |         600.00 |
|           1 | test promo | 2014-07-08 | 2014-08-08 | root@localhost | Company G              | DEMOC     |         650.00 |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+----------------+
```

The component tables look like:

```
 select * from productpromotions;
+-------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+
| promotionid | productid | promotionprice | productdateset      |
+-------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+
|           1 | DEMOA     |         500.00 | 2014-08-07 10:54:07 |
|           1 | DEMOB     |         600.00 | 2014-08-07 00:02:03 |
|           2 | DEMOB     |         650.00 | 2014-08-07 00:02:03 |
|           1 | DEMOC     |         650.00 | 2014-08-07 00:02:07 |
|           3 | DEMOB     |         300.00 | 2014-08-07 00:02:03 |
+-------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+
```

and

```
select * from company_products;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'afl_discounts.company_products' doesn't exist
mysql> select * from company_promotions;
+-------------+------------------------+
| promotionid | company_name           |
+-------------+------------------------+
|           1 | Company G              |
|           2 | Company F              |
|           3 | Company C              |
|           1 | Company F              |
|           3 | Company F              |
+-------------+------------------------+
```

and

```
select * from promotion_general;
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+
| promotionid | name       | startdate  | enddate    | issuer         |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+
|           1 | test promo | 2014-07-08 | 2014-08-08 | root@localhost |
|           2 | promo2     | 2014-08-08 | 2014-09-08 | zakiir         |
|           3 | promo2     | 2014-05-08 | 2014-06-08 | zakiir         |
|           4 | promo3     | 2014-05-08 | 2014-06-08 | zakiir         |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+
```

What would I have to do to make my output look like this?

```
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+----------------+
| promotionid | name       | startdate  | enddate    | issuer         | company_name           | productid | promotionprice |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+----------------+
 |           3 | promo2     | 2014-05-08 | 2014-06-08 | zakiir         | Company C             | DEMOB     |         300.00 |
 |           1 | test promo | 2014-07-08 | 2014-08-08 | root@localhost | Company F             | DEMOA     |         500.00 |
 |           3 | promo2     | 2014-05-08 | 2014-06-08 | zakiir         | Company F             | DEMOB     |         300.00 |
 |           1 | test promo | 2014-07-08 | 2014-08-08 | root@localhost | Company F             | DEMOC     |         650.00 |
 |           1 | test promo | 2014-07-08 | 2014-08-08 | root@localhost | Company G             | DEMOA     |         500.00 |
 |           1 | test promo | 2014-07-08 | 2014-08-08 | root@localhost | Company G             | DEMOB     |         600.00 |
 |           1 | test promo | 2014-07-08 | 2014-08-08 | root@localhost | Company G             | DEMOC     |         650.00 |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+----------------+
```

Where the duplicate, more expensive prices for DEMO B have been removed.

I know it's a long one, but I'm super stumped.

Thanks,

Comment: if you are trying to get the lowest price for each productid then why do you have 600 for DEMOB in the expected results?

Comment: Ah, sorry, because Company G isn't part of the promotion group (promotionid = 3) with that costing, Company G is part of the promotion group 1 (promotion id = 1) which has product DEMO B as $600. It's a little confusing--I do appreciate your initial answer though!

Comment: OK well I have a few ideas of what to try.. I'm out right now but when I get home I'll take a look and see if I can work up a solution

Comment: ok i just edited my answer.. let me know if that does what you want.

Comment: @Strawberry theres one in my answer.

Comment: @zedjay72 i added a fiddle showing the correct results please verify they work for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running this.. I think it'll do what you want.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
(   SELECT 
        cp.promotionid, 
        name, 
        startdate, 
        enddate, 
        issuer, 
        company_name, 
        p.productid, 
        p.promotionprice 
    FROM company_promotions cp
    JOIN productpromotions p ON p.promotionid = cp.promotionid
    JOIN promotion_general pg ON pg.promotionid = cp.promotionid
    ORDER BY cp.promotionid DESC
) t 
GROUP BY company_name, productid
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc53a/1)

Comment: I believe that's it! Thanks for your help John!

Comment: Quick question, why was it necessary to order by the cp.promotionid, initially?

Comment: Because its ordering it in ascending order which was causing incorrect results